# Max Brightness too low on Debian

Tags: debian, drivers, video, brightness

Using Debian wheezy 7.5 x64 on a Acer Aspire 5738Z, I found that maximum brightness (value '9' in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`) is much lower than maximum brightness offered by hardware (i.e., when using windows on the same machine is almost 1.5 times!).
Considering that:

1. many googled related questions suggest that `max_brightness` should be '15' on Debian;
2. the file `max_brightness` is not modifiable by root even with rwx permissions (it says I/O error)

Is there  any workaround to this boundary?

Comment: There aren't other directories in /sys/class/backlight.

Comment: What gpu do you have? Only a intel one ? Or also a dedicated like ati or nvidia ?

Comment: nVidia GeForce G105M with drivers for debian installed

Comment: Optimus running?

Comment: No optimus. Actually i would open another Q for its troubled installation attempt.